# Ansible loop from dictionary

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm looking for a clever way to loop through a dictionary.
My Dict:

```
certmgmt_keys_on_srv:
  aap.tstglobal.tst.loc:
    srv:
      - t28419.tst.loc
      - t28420.tst.loc
      - t28421.tst.loc
    mykey:  /etc/tower/tower.key
    mycert: /etc/tower/tower.cert
    notify: activate_aap_cert
  aap2.tstglobal.tst.loc:
    srv:
      - t38419.tst.loc
      - t38420.tst.loc
      - t38421.tst.loc
    mykey:  /etc/tower/tower3.key
    mycert: /etc/tower/tower2.cert
    notify: activate_aap_cert
```

My idea is that I do a query on the dictonary and get the values ​​in a loop like:

```
item.key = aap.tstglobal.tst.loc
item.value.srv = t28419.tst.loc
item.value.mykey = /etc/tower/tower.key
item.value.mycert = /etc/tower/tower.cert
```

but only if my current hostname (t28419.tst.loc) is present in srv.
In the further course I load the files from the certificate to the current server ...

I've tried the following, but I can't really get any further.
Can someone please help me :-)

```
  - name: Display my cert_names and file_names to renew
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      msg: "Cert_Name: {{ item }}"
    with_subelements:
      - "{{ certmgmt_keys_on_srv | community.general.json_query('*') }}"
      - srv
      - skip_missing: yes
```

And get:

```
TASK [Display my cert_names and file_names to renew] ************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [t28419.tst.loc] => (item=[{'key': '/etc/tower/tower.key', 'cert': '/etc/tower/tower.cert', 'notify': 'activate_aap_cert'}, 't28419.tst.loc']) => {
    "msg": "Cert_Name: [{'key': '/etc/tower/tower.key', 'cert': '/etc/tower/tower.cert', 'notify': 'activate_aap_cert'}, 't28419.tst.loc']"
}
ok: [t28419.tst.loc] => (item=[{'key': '/etc/tower/tower.key', 'cert': '/etc/tower/tower.cert', 'notify': 'activate_aap_cert'}, 't28420.tst.loc']) => {
    "msg": "Cert_Name: [{'key': '/etc/tower/tower.key', 'cert': '/etc/tower/tower.cert', 'notify': 'activate_aap_cert'}, 't28420.tst.loc']"
}
ok: [t28419.tst.loc] => (item=[{'key': '/etc/tower/tower.key', 'cert': '/etc/tower/tower.cert', 'notify': 'activate_aap_cert'}, 't28421.tst.loc']) => {
    "msg": "Cert_Name: [{'key': '/etc/tower/tower.key', 'cert': '/etc/tower/tower.cert', 'notify': 'activate_aap_cert'}, 't28421.tst.loc']"
}
```

Thanks for help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    certmgmt_keys_on_srv:
      aap.tstglobal.tst.loc:
        srv:
          - t28419.tst.loc
          - t28420.tst.loc
          - t28421.tst.loc
        mykey: /etc/tower/tower.key
        mycert: /etc/tower/tower.cert
        notify: activate_aap_cert
      aap2.tstglobal.tst.loc:
        srv:
          - t38419.tst.loc
          - t38420.tst.loc
          - t38421.tst.loc
        mykey: /etc/tower/tower3.key
        mycert: /etc/tower/tower2.cert
        notify: activate_aap_cert

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg:
          key: "{{ item[0] }}"
          srv: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
          mykey: "{{ item[1].mykey }}"
          mycert: "{{ item[1].mycert }}"
      when: inventory_hostname in item[1].srv
      loop: "{{ certmgmt_keys_on_srv.items() }}"
```

Assuming that we have an inventory that defines hosts `t38419.tst.loc` and`t28421.tst.loc`, running the above playbook produces:

```
PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
skipping: [t38419.tst.loc] => (item=['aap.tstglobal.tst.loc', {'srv': ['t28419.tst.loc', 't28420.tst.loc', 't28421.tst.loc'], 'mykey': '/etc/tower/tower.key', 'mycert': '/etc/tower/tower.cert', 'notify': 'activate_aap_cert'}]) 
ok: [t38419.tst.loc] => (item=['aap2.tstglobal.tst.loc', {'srv': ['t38419.tst.loc', 't38420.tst.loc', 't38421.tst.loc'], 'mykey': '/etc/tower/tower3.key', 'mycert': '/etc/tower/tower2.cert', 'notify': 'activate_aap_cert'}]) => {
    "msg": {
        "key": "aap2.tstglobal.tst.loc",
        "mycert": "/etc/tower/tower2.cert",
        "mykey": "/etc/tower/tower3.key",
        "srv": "t38419.tst.loc"
    }
}
ok: [t28421.tst.loc] => (item=['aap.tstglobal.tst.loc', {'srv': ['t28419.tst.loc', 't28420.tst.loc', 't28421.tst.loc'], 'mykey': '/etc/tower/tower.key', 'mycert': '/etc/tower/tower.cert', 'notify': 'activate_aap_cert'}]) => {
    "msg": {
        "key": "aap.tstglobal.tst.loc",
        "mycert": "/etc/tower/tower.cert",
        "mykey": "/etc/tower/tower.key",
        "srv": "t28421.tst.loc"
    }
}
skipping: [t28421.tst.loc] => (item=['aap2.tstglobal.tst.loc', {'srv': ['t38419.tst.loc', 't38420.tst.loc', 't38421.tst.loc'], 'mykey': '/etc/tower/tower3.key', 'mycert': '/etc/tower/tower2.cert', 'notify': 'activate_aap_cert'}]) 

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
t28421.tst.loc             : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
t38419.tst.loc             : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Hello larsks! Many thanks for your support!
Your solution works! You kicked me!
Greetings Isabella

Comment: @Isabella, glad to help! If this answer solved your question, please check the checkmark to the left of the answer to mark it as "accepted".